# No such file or directory sed command in a bash file run inside a docker container

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, sed

I'm trying to run a bash file inside an Ubuntu docker container where i'm trying to modify two files of Postgresql, postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf, here is the bash file that i'm trying to run:

```
   sed -i -e"s/^#listen_addresses.*$/listen_addresses = '*'/" 
   /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
   echo "host    all    all    0.0.0.0/0    md5" >> 
   /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
   /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

here is how i'm trying to run it:

```
   root@fe4fcebedad6: ./db.sh
```

db.sh is the name of the bash file, the file postgresql.conf is in the path that i'm using /var/lib/postgresql/data/ but i'm getting this message:

```
: No such file or directorystgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

The weird part is that if run each one of the commands outside of the bash file it works fine, like this:

```
root@fe4fcebedad6:/# sed -i -e"s/^#listen_addresses.*$/listen_addresses = '*'/" /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

This is the part in the docker-compose file where i'm copying my local bash file into the postgrest image

```
      volumes:
       - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
       - ./shell_scripts:/shell_scripts

volumes:
    pgdata:
```

Comment: What postgresql docker image are you using? Perhaps you are using an image that doesn't have the basic shell tools like sed installed.

Comment: i'm using postgres without specifying the version like this 

db:
      image: postgres

Comment: Make sure that you use the full path in the script i.e. /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue because you have multiple lines in your command. It should be like below

```
sed -i -e"s/^#listen_addresses.*$/listen_addresses = '*'/" /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf

echo "host    all    all    0.0.0.0/0    md5" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf

/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: This didn't worked for me, it gave errors in each of the blank lines, and the issue continued

Answer (score 0):

After several tries, I couldn't make the bash file work, so i removed it and executed each of the commands manually in my docker console.

Thank you anyway.